# how to configure angular-cli project for rc5?

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, angular-cli, ngrx

Trying to install angular-cli to work with angular 2 rc5 and I'm facing some errors:

**Cannot find the name 'Promise'**

I have installed 'npm install -g angular-cli@webpack' and it seems he doesnt install typings so webstorm doesn't know "Promise".

**What I have tryied with no success:**

1.I installed 'npm install typings --save' but there was no change.

2.In the webstorm project configuration I enabled: (Doesn't help)

```
1. Use typescript service (Experimental)
2. Enable typescript compiler
2.1 Track changes
2.2. Use tsconfig.json
```

3.In tsconfig I changed target from es5 to es6 and now webstorm recognize promise/then/catch but typescript throw error that he doesn't know it and now I face new error on every class in every component:

```
export class AppComponent <-- ERROR
{

}
export class AppModule <-- ERROR
{

}
Error:(8, 14) TS1219:Experimental support for decorators is
a feature that is subject to change in a future release.
Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning.
```

This is strange becouse in tsconfig.json : "experimentalDecorators": true.
Even if it is false, there is no change.

**ngrx installation errros and warnings:**

In another topic, when trying to install ngrx/core: 'npm install @ngrx/core --save'

The end of the installtion is:

```
....
....
`-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY typescript@2.0.0       <<-- In red color

npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1
.0.14
npm WARN @angular/tsc-wrapped@0.2.2 requires a peer of typescript@^1.9.0-dev but none
```

I get the same warnings when installing: 'npm install @ngrx/store --save'.

I added in the app.module.ts in the imports array: 'StoreModule.provideStore({EmptyReducer})'.
After 'ng serve' I get the following warnings in the console:

```
WARNING in ./~/@ngrx/store/index.js
Cannot find source file '../src/index.ts': Error: Can't resolve '../src/index.ts' in 'C:\Users\armyTik\Desktop\rc5\store-app-02\node_modules\@ngrx\store'
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts 15:0-42
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi main

WARNING in ./~/@ngrx/store/dispatcher.js
Cannot find source file '../src/dispatcher.ts': Error: Can't resolve '../src/dispatcher.ts' in 'C:\Users\armyTik\Desktop\rc5\store-app-02\node_modules\@ngrx\store'
 @ ./~/@ngrx/store/index.js 5:9-32
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi main

WARNING in ./~/@ngrx/store/ng2.js
Cannot find source file '../src/ng2.ts': Error: Can't resolve '../src/ng2.ts' in 'C:\Users\armyTik\Desktop\rc5\store-app-02\node_modules\@ngrx\store'
 @ ./~/@ngrx/store/index.js 6:9-25
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi main

WARNING in ./~/@ngrx/store/reducer.js
Cannot find source file '../src/reducer.ts': Error: Can't resolve '../src/reducer.ts' in 'C:\Users\armyTik\Desktop\rc5\store-app-02\node_modules\@ngrx\store'
 @ ./~/@ngrx/store/index.js 7:9-29
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi main

WARNING in ./~/@ngrx/store/state.js
Cannot find source file '../src/state.ts': Error: Can't resolve '../src/state.ts' in 'C:\Users\armyTik\Desktop\rc5\store-app-02\node_modules\@ngrx\store'
 @ ./~/@ngrx/store/index.js 8:9-27
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi main

WARNING in ./~/@ngrx/store/store.js
Cannot find source file '../src/store.ts': Error: Can't resolve '../src/store.ts' in 'C:\Users\armyTik\Desktop\rc5\store-app-02\node_modules\@ngrx\store'
 @ ./~/@ngrx/store/index.js 9:9-27
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi main

WARNING in ./~/@ngrx/store/utils.js
Cannot find source file '../src/utils.ts': Error: Can't resolve '../src/utils.ts' in 'C:\Users\armyTik\Desktop\rc5\store-app-02\node_modules\@ngrx\store'
 @ ./~/@ngrx/store/index.js 10:9-27
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi main
```

---

**Some code from my project (It's empty project):**

app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, ApplicationRef } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {StoreModule} from "@ngrx/store";

import { ActionReducer, Action } from '@ngrx/store';

export const EmptyReducer: ActionReducer<number> = (state: number = 0, action: Action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    StoreModule.provideStore({EmptyReducer})
  ],
  providers: [],
  entryComponents: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {

}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "mapRoot": "./",
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6",    <<-- I changed from es5 to es6
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "types": [
      "jasmine"
    ]
  }
}
```

package.json: (I installed 'npm install typings --save' manually)

```
{
  "name": "store-app-02",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/forms": "0.3.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.1",
    "@ngrx/core": "^1.0.2",
    "@ngrx/store": "^2.1.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "typings": "^1.3.2",
    "zone.js": "0.6.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.2.30",
    "@types/protractor": "^1.5.16",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.2",
    "codelyzer": "0.0.26",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "0.13.22",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "0.2.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "0.3.8",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "3.3.0",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "3.13.0",
    "typescript": "^2.0.0"
  }
}
```

Thanks alot for reading.

Comment: were you able to figure out the ngrx issues?  i am facing the same.

Comment: Please follow this: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1723. I will update here as soon as I get the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go to `src/tsconfig.json` and change the target from 'es5' to 'es6'.

Hope it's helps..